# PushStreamContent using SqlDataReader.ExecuteReaderAsync to stream CSV or delimited file to client

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await, sqldatareader

I'm trying to utilize WebAPI to stream a large amount of data from SQL Server to a delimited file without waiting for the entire result set to return from the database.  I'm really terrible with Async and Await, haven't wrapped my head around it.  It seems what I'd like to do should be possible using the PushStreamContent and the SqlDataReader async methods.
This is at my DataAccessLayer:

```
   Public Async Function ExecuteToResponseStream(command As SqlCommand, responseStream As IO.Stream) As Threading.Tasks.Task
      Using responseStream
         Dim newConString As String = _conString
         Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(newConString)
            Await con.OpenAsync()
            'Add params
            command.Connection = con

            Using ms As IO.MemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream
               Using ts As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(ms)

                  Using reader As SqlDataReader = Await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)
                     While Await reader.ReadAsync()
                        Dim loValues As New List(Of String)
                        For i = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
                           loValues.Add(reader(i).ToString)
                        Next
                        Await ts.WriteAsync(String.Join(vbTab, loValues.ToArray))
                        Await ms.CopyToAsync(responseStream)
                     End While
                  End Using
               End Using
            End Using
         End Using
      End Using
   End Function
```

My repository has a method with signature of:
    Function ExportAsync(id As String, responseStream As IO.Stream) As Task

Finally, the WebAPI Client:

```
   Public Function Export(id As String) As HttpResponseMessage
      Dim resp As New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
      Dim onStreamAvailable As Action(Of IO.Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext) = Async Sub(responseStream, content, context)
        Await repository.ExportAsync(rc, responseStream)
     End Sub

      resp.Content = New PushStreamContent(onStreamAvailable)
      resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = New Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream")
      resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = New Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
      resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Somefilename"

      Return resp
   End Function
```

The client function seems to exit appropriately and return the response, eventually.  The eventual response to the browser does indeed look like an attachment, it's empty, I suck at streams, but it seems like it not happening in that magical asynchronous way.

Also, it seems to me that this would be a somewhat simple exercise though I can't find a good implementation out there on the webs.  Perhaps I'm going about this completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've found something that used to / doesn't work.

**Update**

Repository Method

```
Public Async Function ExportToCSV(inputParameters, stream As IO.Stream) As Threading.Tasks.Task
   'Build SqlCommand from inputParameters
   Await sqlClient.ReaderToDelimitedAsync(","c, _SqlCommand, stream)
End Function
```

Custom SqlClient Wrapper Method

```
   Async Function ReaderToDelimitedAsync(delimiter As Char, command As SqlCommand, stream As IO.Stream) As Threading.Tasks.Task
  Try

     Await command.Connection.OpenAsync
     Using rdr As SqlDataReader = Await command.ExecuteReaderAsync
        Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(stream, Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"))
           Dim los As New List(Of String)
           For i = 0 To rdr.FieldCount - 1
              los.Add(String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", ControlChars.Quote, rdr.GetName(i)))
           Next
           Await sw.WriteLineAsync(String.Join(delimiter, los.ToArray))
           Await sw.FlushAsync

           While Await rdr.ReadAsync
              Dim loVals As New List(Of String)
              For i = 0 To rdr.FieldCount - 1
                 Dim strVal As String = rdr.GetValue(i).ToString
                 strVal = strVal.Replace(ControlChars.Quote, Chr(39)).Trim(Chr(10), Chr(13), Chr(32)) '.Replace(Chr(13), " ").Replace(Chr(10), " ")
                 strVal = strVal.Replace(vbCrLf + vbCrLf, vbCrLf).Replace(vbCrLf + vbCrLf, vbCrLf)
                 strVal = strVal.Substring(0, Math.Min(strVal.Length, 32000))
                 loVals.Add(String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", ControlChars.Quote, strVal))
              Next
              Await sw.WriteLineAsync(String.Join(","c, loVals.ToArray))
              Await sw.FlushAsync()
           End While

        End Using
     End Using
  Catch ex As Exception
     Throw ex
  End Try
   End Function
```

And to use it:

```
  <HttpPost, ActionName("Download"), ValidateAntiForgeryHeader(False)> Public Function DownloadReport(postparameters) As HttpResponseMessage

      Dim resp As New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)

         resp.Content = New PushStreamContent(Function(stream, http_content, transportcontextcontext)
                                                 Return repository.Export(postparameters, stream)
                                              End Function, "text/csv")
         resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = New Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv")
     resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = New Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
      resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = reporttemplate.Filename

      Return resp

   End Function
```

I've also tried it like:

```
   <HttpPost, ActionName("Download"), ValidateAntiForgeryHeader(False)> Public Function DownloadReport(postparameters) As HttpResponseMessage

      Dim resp As New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)

         resp.Content = New PushStreamContent(Async Function(stream, http_content, transportcontextcontext)
                                                 Await repository.Export(postparameters, stream)
                                              End Function, "text/csv")
         resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = New Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv")
     resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = New Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
      resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = reporttemplate.Filename

      Return resp

   End Function
```

The problem is that the download doesn't start at the client until the SqlDataReader closes (the End Using statement).  My understanding is that the PushStreamContent should return upon the first Await it encounters, and the subsequent calls to FlushAsync should start the delivery of the stream to the client.
I'm still terrible understanding this Async Await pattern.  Any thoughts?